# An error is diplayed when I try to add a new PackageReference in project

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

The error in the tab output of Visual Studio Code:

> c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Formation
> Core\Project\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj : error
> NU1100: Impossible de r�soudre 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>=
> 3.1.2)' pour '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.   �chec de la restauration dans 85,11 ms pour c:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Formation
> Core\Project\DatingApp\DatingApp.API\DatingApp.API.csproj.

my version of .NET Core is 3.0.1

Comment: The command to add PachageReference : >dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an incompatibility between your .NET Core version and the EF Core version. According to Microsoft's official EF Core 3 documentation, you should apply .NET Standard 2.0 to your project again to make EF Core 3.1 compatible.
Check this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#netstandard21

Comment: can you give the steps to flow to resolve this problem . thanks a loooot

Comment: To change the target framework: Right click on your project --> Properties --> Application --> Target Framework

Comment: but be ware that changing it might impact in other stuff on the project. Try to build it to see if any errors pop up

Comment: The project file has a tag named TargetFramework. Try to change it to something like <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

Comment: it should perform the same result

Comment: thanks for your help. the problem its from the config file of nuget i change this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <activePackageSource>
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" /> 
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>


to 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
 
  
</packageSources>
</configuration>

Comment: odd issue, never saw anything like it before